# Call graphs in Soot

Tags: java, eclipse, call-graph, soot

How do I use SOOT to build at Call graph? Or are there any better programs for this? I have been sent around the same five pages looking for answers and I can't find what I am looking for. There are also a problem with the plugin version to Eclipse. It is installed correct but I cant choose it when I want to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples include call graph for Java. http://www.brics.dk/SootGuide/

And call graph for apk.
https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow/issues/38

If you want to get the dot file, you can iterate over the callgraph and write the contents out in dot format like this.

```java
private static void visit(CallGraph cg, SootMethod method) {
  String identifier = method.getSignature();
  visited.put(method.getSignature(), true);
  dot.drawNode(identifier);
  // iterate over unvisited parents
  Iterator<MethodOrMethodContext> ptargets = new Targets(cg.edgesInto(method));
  if (ptargets != null) {
    while (ptargets.hasNext()) {
        SootMethod parent = (SootMethod) ptargets.next();
        if (!visited.containsKey(parent.getSignature())) visit(cg, parent);
    }
  }
    // iterate over unvisited children
    Iterator<MethodOrMethodContext> ctargets = new Targets(cg.edgesOutOf(method));
  if (ctargets != null) {
    while (ctargets.hasNext()) {
       SootMethod child = (SootMethod) ctargets.next();
       dot.drawEdge(identifier, child.getSignature());
       System.out.println(method + " may call " + child);
       if (!visited.containsKey(child.getSignature())) visit(cg, child);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Small modification to previous answer

```js
private static void visit(CallGraph cg, SootMethod method) {
  String identifier = method.getSignature();
  visited.put(method.getSignature(), true);
  dot.drawNode(identifier);
  // iterate over unvisited parents
  Iterator<MethodOrMethodContext> ptargets = new Sources(cg.edgesInto(method));
  if (ptargets != null) {
    while (ptargets.hasNext()) {
        SootMethod parent = (SootMethod) ptargets.next();
        if (!visited.containsKey(parent.getSignature())) visit(cg, parent);
    }
}
```