# How do I exclude java standard libraries from call graphs generated by Soot?

Tags: java, static-analysis, call-graph, soot

I currently working on an automatic code documentation tool. For it, I am using Soot for constructing the call graph. However, Soot seems to be including the standard java libraries in this call graph. This is of course, not desirable since I am only interested in the actual classes of the program that I will be generating documentation for.

This is program I used to test the callgraph:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        List<String> argsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[0]));
        argsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
            "-w",
            "-no-bodies-for-excluded",
            "-process-dir",
            args[1], //directory with the java files
            "-src-prec",
            "java",
            "-main-class",
            args[2] //main class
        }));

        String[] trueArgs = argsList.toArray(new String[0]);
        Main.v().run(trueArgs);
        CallGraph cg = Scene.v().getCallGraph();
        visit(cg , Scene.v().getEntryPoints().get(0));
    }
```

With following function to iterate over the call graph (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993349/call-graphs-in-soot)):

```
    private static void visit(CallGraph cg, SootMethod method) {
          String identifier = method.getSignature();
          visited.put(method.getSignature(), true);
          dot.drawNode(identifier);
          // iterate over unvisited parents
          Iterator<MethodOrMethodContext> ptargets = new Sources(cg.edgesInto(method));
          if (ptargets != null) {
            while (ptargets.hasNext()) {
                SootMethod parent = (SootMethod) ptargets.next();
                if (!visited.containsKey(parent.getSignature())) visit(cg, parent);
            }
          }
          // iterate over unvisited children
          Iterator<MethodOrMethodContext> ctargets = new Targets(cg.edgesOutOf(method));
          if (ctargets != null) {
            while (ctargets.hasNext()) {
               SootMethod child = (SootMethod) ctargets.next();
               dot.drawEdge(identifier, child.getSignature());
               System.out.println(method + " may call " + child);
               if (!visited.containsKey(child.getSignature())) visit(cg, child);
            }
          }
    }
```

However, while testing I have been recording such calls:

```
[...]
<callgraphs.A: void <init>()> may call <java.lang.Object: void <init>()>
<java.lang.Thread: void <init>(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.Runnable)> may call <java.lang.Object: void <clinit>()>
<java.lang.Thread: void <init>(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.String)> may call <java.lang.Object: void <clinit>()>
<java.lang.Thread: void <init>(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.String)> may call <java.lang.Object: void <init>()>
<java.lang.Thread: void <init>(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.String)> may call <java.lang.Thread: void init(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.Runnable,java.lang.String,long)>
<java.lang.Thread: void <init>(java.lang.ThreadGroup,java.lang.String)> may call <java.lang.Object: void <init>()>
[...]
```

Followed by lots of calls between java libraries.

Is there a way to make Soot simply ignore the standard java libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

We just suppress the `visit` calls from classes from the java package.

so by using `child.isJavaLibraryMethod()` to check if it is from the java package.

If it is from the java package we simply do not call `visit` with that class, so by adding this check for the parent and child calls and suppressing the output, we get the correct callgraph. (and as a bonus it is much faster as you're not traversing the java library anymore.

so the code is changed to:

```
private static void visit(CallGraph cg, SootMethod method) {
          String identifier = method.getSignature();
          visited.put(method.getSignature(), true);
          dot.drawNode(identifier);
          // iterate over unvisited parents
          Iterator<MethodOrMethodContext> ptargets = new Sources(cg.edgesInto(method));
          if (ptargets != null) {
            while (ptargets.hasNext()) {
                SootMethod parent = (SootMethod) ptargets.next();
                if (!visited.containsKey(parent.getSignature()) && !parent.isJavaLibraryMethod()) visit(cg, parent);
            }
          }
          // iterate over unvisited children
          Iterator<MethodOrMethodContext> ctargets = new Targets(cg.edgesOutOf(method));
          if (ctargets != null) {
            while (ctargets.hasNext()) {
               SootMethod child = (SootMethod) ctargets.next();
               dot.drawEdge(identifier, child.getSignature());
               if (!child.isJavaLibraryMethod())System.out.println(method + " may call " + child);
               if (!visited.containsKey(child.getSignature()) && !child.isJavaLibraryMethod()) visit(cg, child);
            }
          }
    }
```